# configure remote server's apache and php to locate a website

Tags: apache2, php, remote-access

I need to locate website files to remote machine which runs CentOS with no graphical user interface. My machine runs ubuntu. Is there a way to check configuration of installed apache and php or how to configure them in order to run my site? I have been told that CentOS uses almost the same commands with ubuntu as it is considered one of linux based system. I had already copied all my website files to remote machine's /var/www/html directory. I have tried following:

- open browse from my local machine and try to open that remote addres/website/directory/  error: requested url couldn't be retrieved.
- chmod 777 -R /path/to/website/dir/

but no use. website is not working, so i think i have to configure apache and php together.

Comment: "chmod 777 -R /path/to/website/dir/" change that back to 755 for dirs and 644 for files please. To me this seems like a config issue on the system that holds the webserver. CentOS goes here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am an ubuntu user and developed my site with the aid of ubuntu's apache and php. In this case i need to just locate my site on another machine running with other OS considered as almost the same. As i am not Unix & Linux Stack Exchange member and the answer was needed urgently, i have asked my question here.

Comment: No, you need the server (=centos) to accept your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu and CentOS use different configurations and paths for Apache and PHP for example Ubuntu lists each virtualhost in the **/etc/apache2/sites-available** and CentOS stores the virtualhost config in the main **/etc/httpd/httpd.conf file**.

In order to setup the Apache config on CentOS you need to copy the content of the /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site and paste it in the /etc/httpd/httpd.conf file and restart Apache on CentOS

For PHP you need to compare the configs from Ubuntu located at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini with the one from CentOS located at /etc/php.ini.

Comment: We only deal with problems related to Ubuntu ;)

Comment: Thanks, i have changed httpd.conf file uncommenting Virtualhosts section and now it is working. Appreciation!